# Handler inside IntentService

Tags: android, handler, intentservice

I am using an `IntentService` to download something from the Internet to my `Android app`.
I am also using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/  `httpClient`, which is also `async`.

The problem I have is that when I fire the download `async` call, the `IntentService` thread finishes and the `http` client cannot callback with the response because the `Service` thread is dead.

I have used a Handler like this and it seems to work but I am a little bit lost about the loppers . Is this correct? Am I safe using this code as it is?

```
new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //my downloading code here
        }
}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intent Service provide a background thread itself, so what you should do is do straight http calls in its onHandleIntent method and interact with your activity through broadcasts.

On the other hand, I have never used loopj but it looks to provide all the asyncness you need out of the box. I would ask myself why I need to use it inside an intentservice. If you need to have it running while the app is backgrounded, a better solution would be to use it inside a more classical service.

The workaround you are trying to implement is against the nature of intentservices, which is simple worker threads that expire after handling the intent.

Comment: I started using the IntentService because it is pretty simple to implement but then I found this issue. I wanted to be consistent and use loopj http async client everywhere in my app so that's why I ended up using the solution I mention on my question. But you are right, a classic service will do the job in a better way.

Comment: Use SyncHttp instead of AsynHttp and you are good to go.I have used this in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It seems to be safe since Your

> download async call

will work on separate thread (most probably).